# Wondering why the book we're using is using doubles and decimals instead of just decimals

Tags: c#

I'm wondering why the book we're using's example is using a mix of decimals and doubles with a cast to decimal when necessary. Would it not be simpler to just make everything decimals and avoid the casts altogether?

Here's the main chunk of code that I'm curious about.

```
decimal amount;
decimal principal = 1000;
double rate = 0.05;

for (int year = 1; year <= 10; year++)
{
    amount = principal * ((decimal) Math.Pow(1.0 + rate, year));
}
```

Are there any performance or accuracy issues that I'm overlooking?

Comment: Math.Pow has no overload that takes decimals.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no overload of `Math.Pow` that works with `decimal`  - exponentiation on reals is inherently inaccurate, so it wouldn't make all that much sense for such an overload to exist.

Now since the only place where `rate` is used is in calculating the compound factor (the `Pow` call), it makes sense for it to be declared `double` - higher precision wouldn't help if it's going to just be 'cast away'.

The rest of the variables represent money, which is *the* use-case for `decimal` (that's why the suffix for `decimal` literals is `M`). One could imagine another computation where `commmision` of `$2.10` were added to `amount` - we don't want such calculations to become inaccurate all for the sake of type-consistency in one pesky (inaccurate) compound-interest calculation.

Hence the inconsistency.

Comment: Ah, so it doesn't. I understand the main differences between `decimal` and `double`, and that's actually why I asked - we're already working with decimals in that equation, so the performance gain between the two is sort of moot. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Decimal has a smaller range, but is more accurate than double.  Decimal is what you should use to represent money in .Net.  In the example you gave, amount and principal are monetary values.  Rate is not.  Thus, they are using the correct data types.

Here is the MSDN on Decimal: [MSDN Decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28DECIMAL_CSHARPKEYWORD%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true)

Answer (score 0):

You should read [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165761/decimal-vs-double-which-one-should-i-use-and-when)

What it boils down to is: decimal is used for money/when you need precision in calculations, whereas double is more suited for scientific calculation because it performs better.